# Image in DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, .net

I cant get this code work. I need to load an image on a datagridview cell.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
dgvListadoPedido.Columns.Add(img);
img.Name = "img";
img.HeaderText = "Estado";

for (int i = 0; i < dgvListadoPedido.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dgvListadoPedido.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = image;
               //     dgvListadoPedido.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = BurgaKuroda.Clinica.Win.Properties.Resources.busq3;
                }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I put :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvListadoPedido.Rows.Count; i++)
{
        dgvListadoPedido.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = BurgaKuroda.Clinica.Win.Properties.Resources.busq3;
}
```

Into the `DataBindingComplete` event. And now it works pretty fine.